# How is the best way to recognize frames with contains only white text on red gradient background?

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, opencv

I'm capturing frames from video stream. In random moments, on constant place there is white text on the red gradient background.
I want to get text from this frames (I use pytesseract) and save it to the database, so how can I detect that frames?
When frames don't contains text, pytesseract returns senseless things and my code sends them to the database - this is unacceptable. Frames are cropped, so contains only [white text on red background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsUt6.jpg) (only capital letters, one or two lines) or [other random content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CPLF.jpg). Sometimes can be possible situation when cropped is not good because the height of the red rectangle is reduced like [this combination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAu7Z.jpg) or unfortunately there is [other text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPNtK.jpg). In these cases pytesseract is weak.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import time
import mysql.connector
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

recent = ""
while True:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(VIDEO_URL)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)[815:970, 360:1920] #crop frame
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
    if SequenceMatcher(None, recent, text).ratio() < 0.5: #save only when text is new
        sql = "INSERT INTO table(content, date) VALUES(%s ,%s)"
        val = (text, time.localtime())
        mycursor.execute(sql, val)
        db.commit()
        recent = text
```

How can I improve this solution and processing only croped frames with white text on red gradient background?
Is something better then pytesseract for this solution?

Comment: Regarding the letters you are looking for, is the font always a known font of a fixed size, or at least, one of 2-3 fonts and sizes?

Comment: Have you considered using `inRange()` to make a mask of red pixels and a mask of white pixels, adding the two masks and seeing what percentage of the total area is neither red nor white?

Comment: Font is always the same, but font size is variable (two-three sizes)

Comment: You could maybe consider OpenCV *"template matching"* against those sizes.

Comment: you might want to try filtering out the background and inverting so text is black on white background. If the random text is never white then you can remove it easily to background.

Answer (score 1):

You can use color filtering to find a mask and then based on the percentage of area occupied by mask you can decide whether you need to extract the text of not.
Modified code :

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import time
import numpy as np
import mysql.connector
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

# bound for red colour
lower_red = np.array([0, 50, 50])
upper_red = np.array([10, 255, 255])

threshold = 35
recent = ""
while True:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(VIDEO_URL)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)[815:970, 360:1920] #crop frame

    h, w = img.shape[:2]

    # converting to hsv
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    
    # filtering 
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
    
    # percentage of area which is red
    total = h * w
    count = cv2.countNonZero(mask)
    percentage = (100 * count) / total
    
    if SequenceMatcher(None, recent, text).ratio() < 0.5 and percentage >= threshold: #save only when text is new
        custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6'
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(mask, config=custom_config)
        sql = "INSERT INTO table(content, date) VALUES(%s ,%s)"
        val = (text, time.localtime())
        mycursor.execute(sql, val)
        db.commit()
        recent = text
```

Also you can improve this by finding the largest connected component in `mask` and considering that part only